# unable to connect to a remote windows xp machine using putty

Tags: windows-xp, ssh, putty

i have problem to connect to a remote windows xp machine using putty with an admin account.

when trying i get an "**access denied**" message

anyone have an idea of what can cause the problem ?

Comment: Windows doesn't have an SSH server built in; which SSH server have you installed?

Comment: i have openssh installed

Answer (score 1):

Did you create user (and password) for OpenSSH? OpenSSH don't use the same windows users.

Comment: thanks ! that solves the problem. it seems to me that openssh add automatically admin users to the passwd file.

Answer (score 0):

Do have physical access to that machine ? Maybe it's due to firewall rules or even sshd configuration.

Except for the case that you don't write the password correctly :> , sshd may be configured to reject any try to connect to the server.

At least in linux, you could see that in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. No idea for windows